# error C2248: cannot access protected member declared in class

Tags: c++, boost

```
class TClass
{
    class EmbeddClass
    {
        public:
        ....

        protected:
            virtual ~EmbeddClass() {}

    }   

    boost::scoped_ptr<EmbeddClass> scpEmbeddClass;
}
```

The vs2010 complains the above code. I can fix the problem by defining the `~EmbeddClass` as a public function.

Question> what is the cause of this problem? is it because the destructor of scoped_ptr cannot access the protected  `~EmbeddClass` ? It seems to me that shared_ptr has no such an issue.

Thank you

Comment: In the case of `shared_ptr` it depends on how you initialize it. You can actually have that exact issue if you try to store a `EmbeddClass` (and not a derived type)

Answer (score 1):

> Question> what is the cause of this problem? is it because the destructor of scoped_ptr cannot access the protected ~EmbeddClass ?

Yes, that is exactly the issue.

> It seems to me that shared_ptr has no such an issue.

I can only assume that you are not storing `EmbeddClass` objects, but rather objects of a type derived from it in the `shared_ptr`. In that case, the constructor of the shared pointer will create a *deleter* that will call the destructor of the most derived type (as seen by the `shared_ptr` constructor/`reset()`/..). Because the most derived type is destroyed by the `shared_ptr` even if the type mentions the base, it won't call the base destructor.

Answer (score 0):

> is it because the destructor of scoped_ptr cannot access the protected
>   ~EmbeddClass ?

Yes.

> It seems to me that shared_ptr has no such an issue.

Note that you can have multiple `shared_ptr` owning a resource, if you do not initialize it or the use count is more than 1, it will never need to call the deleter. However, `scoped_ptr` is more like `unique_ptr`, it has *unique ownership* over the resource and makes sure that it can delete the pointer even if you do not initialize it.

Basically, a `shared_ptr` that does not own a resource does not require access to the protected destructor while `scoped_ptr` and `unique_ptr` do require access.